# Configure GWT in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

Installed Google `App Engine 1.2.5` and `Web Toolkit 1.7.1`. However I still get a red underline whenever I import `gwt` and user any of it's classes like `graphCanvas`. How do I take this underline away? What haven't I configured correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, I might be missing something, but I can't find any class named graphCanvas or GraphCanvas inside the [gwt 1.7.1 API](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/index.html?overview-summary.html)? Are you sure graphCanvas is correct? Perhaps graphCanvas is included in a thirdparty jar outside gwt and you need to add that to your ecipse project's classpath?

Answer (score 2):

[Better way to use GWT on eclipse is to  use the plugin provide by google](http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/getting_started.html)

Red lines are due to GWT libraries missing from project classpath, either add it manually or use the above plugin